# How exactly does NetTrain use a ValidationSet (can we reuse it as TestSet)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Typically when you train a model you have three sets of data: **training**, **validation**, and **testing** - and they can’t be mixed, i.e. you can’t use images from one in the other.

I want to know if the samples that you give `NetTrain` through the option `ValidationSet` are used to effect the parameters of the network? Or is it considered a *holdout* that I can test on later, or is that data burnt after NetTrain completes?

For example, given that testData is already used in NetTrain:

```
trainingData = ResourceData["MNIST", "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData["MNIST", "TestData"];
lenetModel = NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"]
n = NetTrain[NetModel["LeNet"], trainingData, ValidationSet -> testData]
```

Is this an ill-informed thing to do:

```
ClassifierMeasurements[n, testData]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do `ClassifierMeasurements` on the testData.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksRegularization.html

[image]